# How to reference the inner text of a drop down box

Tags: c#, asp.net

im trying to check for a specific word in a dropdown box before sending an SMS 
this is what i have

```
 if (grdvHandSets.Rows[i].Cells[4].Text == "Port" && grdvHandSets.Rows[i].Cells[16].Text != String.Empty) //Only send SMS if Type = Port and ConDate isnt empty
            {
                SmsBody = string.Format("Your order has been despatched to" + lblDespatchPostCode.Text + ". via Royal Mail next day special delivery. Your number/s are due to transfer on" + grdvHandSets.Rows[i].Cells[16].Text + ". Kind Regards BPD");
                //objSms.SendSms(phonenum, SmsBody);
            }
```

Its the first part where im saying grdvHandSets.Rows[i].Cells[4].Text == "Port" which is a drop down box i thought text would work but it comes up with "" when im debugging.... any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var ddlTxt =  ((DropDownList)grdvHandSets.Rows[i].Cells[4].FindControl("ddlName")).SelectedItem.Text;
id(ddlTxt == "Port" && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlTxt))
{
      //your msg
}
```

Comment: I think your `IsNullOrEmpty` call is a bit wayward.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to get the text from a control within the `TableCell`, not from the cell itself.

You'll probably want `grdvHandSets.Rows[i].Cells[4].Controls[0].Text` but there may be other controls in the cell. Check `grdvHandSets.Rows[i].Cells[4].Controls` in your debugger to see.